# Access previous field value using "Accumulate Field" node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to access the field value under the previous index (previously evaluated value).

The *"Accumulate Field"* node requirement is due to my need to access the value within the pass that it is evaluated; in other words, I want to access it before the last value of this field has been evaluated.

A simple example of the problem is randomizing the values, but making sure no two same values are neighbors:

[image] [image]

A separate pass changing the duplicates using "Field at Index" node, would not only unnecessarily change all marked "2", but with random replacement would again risk some or replacements to be repeated, as well as risk the last "2" to change to "0", converting the second last digit to a duplicate.

In this specific case perhaps a workaround could be made: iterate over duplicates (if field at previous index = field at current index), adding accumulated 1 to each, and if the last duplicate turns out to equal the following field value, add 1 more. This would produce an excess of incremental sequences (3, 4, 5, 6, 7; 12, 13, 14, 15 etc.) which could be passed through some shuffled translation (e.g. `{0: 5, 1:3, 2:0, 3:4, 4:2}`) but this would still create a repeating pattern and turn out to be much more complex than simply accessing a previous field value, if even possible… As well as the problem doesn't always involve random numbers or isn't always as simple (problem inspired by [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/286020/60486) question, where I need to access 3 previous brick colors).

So, is there some combination of chaining and subtracting *"Accumulate Fields"* to get the previous field value?

Comment: Just now realized ( debugging) this ultimately only works if the resulting, fixed number can be accessed by the next evaluation, ultimately meaning the Accumulate Field node would need to access itself. This is not possible. Maybe I'll redact the question later to allow for some workarounds… I can't count how many times I struggled with this variations of this issue only to figure out it's impossible and then forget and struggle with it again…

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are still working on a solution that prevents the `Random Value` node from generating two equal consecutive values, right?

Comment: I thought about it. I don't quite get the *"chaining and substracting"* part. Do you have another example of this?

Comment: @quellenform the problems comes down to: have a function applied to a field, which can read the previous output of the same function. Unsolvable problem in geonodes so far…

Comment: Ah, thank you, now I understand. We have been at this point a few times :)